# Break out of a qx.data.Array forEach loop?

Tags: qooxdoo

Is there a way to break out of the Qooxdoo qx.data.Array forEach loop?

For example,

```
 myarray.forEach(function(obj){
   if(obj.match(/ra/i)){
       //break out of the loop
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, thats not possible. If you need that, you could think about using a regular for loop and break on the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the version that existed in 2013 but currently there is the array method **`some`**. If you return a Boolean **`true`** from the function passed in, the loop will terminate.

```
myarray.some(function(obj) {
    if(obj.match(/ra/i))
    {
        // do something
        return true;
    }
}, this);
```